# dataclass requiring a value after being defined as Optional

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

In the snippet below, I can't understand why I need to **explicitly** provide a value for the `TimeCollection`.  How do I set this up so the line becomes `plan1 = TimeCollection()`

```
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass
import datetime
from typing import Optional, List

@dataclass
class Event():
    event_type: str
    event_date: datetime.datetime

@dataclass
class Timeline():
    name: str
    events: List[Event]
    linked_timeline: Optional[Timeline]
        
@dataclass
class TimelineCollection():
    timelines: Optional[List[Timeline]]
    def add(self, tl:Timeline) -> None :
        self.timelines.append(tl)
        

plan1 = TimelineCollection([])
app2_tl = Timeline(name="APP2", events=[], linked_timeline=None)
plan1.add(app2_tl)
app1_tl = Timeline(name="APP1", events=[
    Event(event_type="Replace Attempt Scheduled", event_date=datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 31)),
    Event(event_type="Replace Attempt Successful", event_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1)),
    Event(event_type="Replaced", event_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1))],
    linked_timeline=app2_tl
)
plan1.add(app1_tl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `Optional` might not be the correct annotation in this case. `Optional[T]` is equivalent to [`T | None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#union-type) in the new style annotations, which implies that the value might be either of type `T`, or an explicit `None` value.

In the scope of dataclasses, fields annotated as `Optional[T]` would ideally be assigned a default value of `None`, for instance such as:

```
field: T | None = None
```

I note that in your case, it appears you are instantiating `plan1` using:

```
plan1 = TimelineCollection([])
```

This implies that the default value for the `timelines` field should actually be an empty `list`.

This can then by accomplished with [`field(default_factory=...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#default-factory-functions) as shown below. Setting a `default` value is not recommended since the type is `list`, which is a mutable type in Python.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class TimelineCollection:
    timelines: list[Timeline] = field(default_factory=list)

plan1 = TimelineCollection()
print(plan1)
```

Prints:

```
TimelineCollection(timelines=[])
```